# Backendless hangs in AsynsCall

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, backendless

I have a function that tries to retrieve data from Backendless "Question" table:

```
private static void fetchQuestionsBase() {
            final Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0);
            Log.d(TAG,"Inside fetch()");
            AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Question>> callback = new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Question>>() {
                @Override
                public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Question> response) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Success in fetching the database");
                    s.release();
                    dataHolder.q = response.getData();
                }
                @Override
                public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Failure: "+fault.getMessage());
                    s.release();
                }
            };
            Backendless.Data.of(Question.class).find(callback);
            Log.d(TAG,"After Data.of...");
            try {
                Log.d(TAG,"Inside try()");
                s.acquire();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"After acquire()");
        }
```

However, this one hangs on "Inside try()" log-message. How can I learn more about this and debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Backendless does not hang here, it looks like a problem with the semaphore. Set a breakpoint inside of handleResponse and see if the execution gets to that point.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've solved this issue in a somewhat ad hoc manner; without semaphores BTW. Since the changes are, as I said, "ad hoc", I thought it might be better to delete this question.

Comment: I would keep it here with a resolution suggesting to avoid semaphores. It might be of some value to others.. Just my $0.02..